# Migrate class from thread-unsafe to thread-safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, struts

### Background

The Apache [Action](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts/action/Action.html) class is not thread-safe. However, this was only realized after implementing a base class, upon which all other classes in the system depend. The base class uses a number of instance variables:

```
  private HttpServletRequest request;
  private ArrayList inputParams = new ArrayList();
  private Connection connection;
  private String outputParameter;
  private boolean exportEnabled;
```

Fortunately, all usages of those variables are accomplished through accessor methods, exclusively. For example:

```
  public boolean getExportEnabled() {
    return this.exportEnabled;
  }

  public void setExportEnabled( boolean exportEnabled ) {
    this.exportEnabled = exportEnabled;
  }
```

### Problem

The base class is running in a multi-threaded Servlet environment.

#### Solution #1

To resolve this issue, I was thinking about using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) keyed to the session. However, this would require re-writing all of the methods, and dependent code:

```
  private static HashMap sessionVariables = new HashMap();

  public boolean getExportEnabled( HttpSession session ) {
    return getSessionVariables().get( session.getId() + '.exportEnabled' );
  }

  public void setExportEnabled( boolean exportEnabled, HttpSession session ) {
    getSessionVariables().put( session.getId() + '.exportEnabled', exportEnabled );
  }
```

That is a lot of work, and would likely introduce bugs.

#### Solution #2

It might be possible to change the base class to an "empty" class. This empty class would have a single method:

```
  public ActionForward execute(
    ActionMapping mapping,
    ActionForm form,
    HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response )
    throws Exception {

    // Instantiate "this" and forward the request?
  }
```

But it would have to know the appropriate base class to instantiate, or perhaps instantiate a new version of itself to handle the call.

#### Update #1

I believe the Struts architecture does the following:

1. Create an instance of the Action subclass.
2. Re-use that same instance for every request.
3. Obtain a thread (from a thread pool) when receiving a new connection.
4. Call `execute` on the Action subclass from the thread.
5. Handle multiple new connections using different threads.

The same `execute` method will be called on the same instance of the object, resulting in unsafe behaviour because the subclass has instance variables.

#### Update #2

The following solution seems to solve the issue:

```
  public ActionForward execute(
          ActionMapping mapping,
          ActionForm form,
          HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response ) throws Exception {
      ((MyClass)clone()).executeClone( mapping, form, request, response );
  }

  public ActionForward executeClone(
          ActionMapping mapping,
          ActionForm form,
          HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response ) throws Exception {

      // Former "execute" method code goes here.
      // ...
  }
```

The original `execute` method was renamed to `executeClone`. The new `execute` implementation creates a clone of the current class and subsequently calls `executeClone`. This minimally invasive technique avoids introducing new bugs while making the class thread-safe.

### Question

What would be the most reliable way to make the code thread-safe while minimizing the risk of introducing bugs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1 is dangerous because it assumes that the session is thread-safe, which is not necessarily the case. Someone could be making two simultaneous requests with the same session.

Solution #2 could be easily implemented by making your base class implement `Cloneable`. Then it can clone itself, set the clone's instance variables, and then call `super.execute()`. If you think it's too hard to change the design to make your base class be properly thread-safe, this might be an easy way out.

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the most reliable way to make the code thread-safe while minimizing the risk of introducing bugs?

There is no general answer to this.  What you need to do to make a class thread-safe depends on what the class does, its API design ... and what level of thread-safety you require.  In some cases, it is not even practical to make something thread-safe; e.g. read the javadoc for `Collections.synchonizedList` and look about how it handles the `iterator()` method.

Comment: agree, actions are not supposed to be thread safe, you should evaluate which portion of your code requires to be thread safe and synchronize such portions

Comment: @Subin: From the API: "Actions **must be programmed in a thread-safe manner**, because the controller will share the same instance for multiple simultaneous requests." Also, there are obvious concurrency bugs when more than 1 user uses the application simultaneously, so thread-safety *is* the culprit in this case.